# Convert razor to aspx in MVC3

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, c#-4.0

HI guys i have a razor file Index.cshtml which needs to be converted to aspx...can any one help me how to declare the classes and model every thing in .cshtml to .aspx

Here is my `Index.cshtml` code

**Index.cshtml**

---

```
@model  IEnumerable<Gridview_BugTracker.Models.BugTracker_DataHelper>
@{
    ViewBag.Title = "Projects";
}          

<p>
    @Html.ActionLink("Create New", "Create")
</p>
<table>
    <tr>
        <th>
            ProjectName
        </th>
        <th>
            Description     
        </th>
        <th>
            Status
        </th>
    </tr>

    @foreach (var item in Model)
    {
    <tr>
        <td>
            @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.projectName)
        </td>
        <td>
            @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.Description)
        </td>
        <td>
            @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.status)
        </td>       
        <td>
            @Html.ActionLink("Edit", "Edit", new { id = item.projectName }) |
            @Html.ActionLink("Details", "Details", new { id = item.Description }) |
            @Html.ActionLink("Delete", "Delete", new { id = item.status })
        </td>
    </tr>
    }
</table>
```

please can any one tell me how to write this code in aspx of MVC3

Comment: @jimtollan i did that, i am geting an error at <%@ Page Title="" Language="C#" MasterPageFile="~/Views/Shared/SiteMaster.Master" Inherits="System.Web.Mvc.ViewPage<IEnumerable<BugTracker.Models.ProjectModel>>" %> saying invalid expressionterm foreach..

Answer (score 1):

anil,

it bugged me that you found this so difficult to do that i had to come back and give you the base details on how to do it yourself (teach a man to fish etc.. :-)). anyway, from the top, do the NORMAL stuff that aspx pages have, in your case:

```
<%@ Page Language="C#" MasterPageFile="~/Views/Shared/Site.Master" 
Inherits="System.Web.Mvc.ViewPage<IEnumerable<Gridview_BugTracker.Models.BugTracker_DataHelper>>" %>
```

ok, now onto a sample block:

razor:

```
@foreach (var item in Model)
```

aspx:

```
<% foreach (var item in Model) { %>
    //... stuff 
    <%: Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.Description) %>
    // more stuff
    <%: Html.ActionLink("Edit", "Edit", new { id = item.projectName }) %> |
    <%: Html.ActionLink("Details", "Details", new { id = item.Description })%> |
<% } %>
```

as you can see, purely syntax changes required that should take no more than 5 mins really.

Good luck -let me know how it all pans out.