# Code conversion from Razor to aspx

Tags: asp.net-mvc

Good day. I got a code snippet of the internet on how to implement paged lists in my view. The problem is that its in razor..

here is the code

```
<div>
    Page @(Model.PageCount < Model.PageNumber ? 0 : Model.PageNumber)
    of @Model.PageCount

    @if (Model.HasPreviousPage)
    {
        @Html.ActionLink("<<", "Index", new { page = 1, sortOrder = ViewBag.CurrentSort, currentFilter=ViewBag.CurrentFilter  })
        @Html.Raw(" ");
        @Html.ActionLink("< Prev", "Index", new { page = Model.PageNumber - 1, sortOrder = ViewBag.CurrentSort, currentFilter=ViewBag.CurrentFilter  })
    }
    else
    {
        @:<<
        @Html.Raw(" ");
        @:< Prev
    }

    @if (Model.HasNextPage)
    {
        @Html.ActionLink("Next >", "Index", new { page = Model.PageNumber + 1, sortOrder = ViewBag.CurrentSort, currentFilter=ViewBag.CurrentFilter  })
        @Html.Raw(" ");
        @Html.ActionLink(">>", "Index", new { page = Model.PageCount, sortOrder = ViewBag.CurrentSort, currentFilter=ViewBag.CurrentFilter  })
    }
    else
    {
        @:Next >
        @Html.Raw(" ")
        @:>>
    }
</div>
```

Can anyone Please help me convert this to ASPX

Comment: possible duplicate: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11465915/convert-razor-to-aspx-in-mvc3

Answer (score 0):

@Bonz_oh if you'd like to get good attention here in SO, try and show that you have exerted some efforts. A more specific problem like ***"I have tried this but it doesn't work, and here's the error I'm getting..."*** would get more attention and help from the guys here. Having said that, I'd like to give you a break so you will not lose heart in asking questions here in SO. But I also would like to encourage you to be self-motivated and for that reason I won't convert your code line-by-line but instead point you to [a blog that I believe can help you tremendously](http://haacked.com/archive/2011/01/06/razor-syntax-quick-reference.aspx). In addition, following SO's guidelines of not just posting links in an answer, I'll point out a couple of conversion you can do in your code:

## 1

Your razor code

```
@if (Model.HasNextPage)
{
}
```

to aspx

```
<% if (Model.HasNextPage) { %> 
<% } %>
```

## 2

You razor code

```
@:Next >
@Html.Raw(" ")
@:>>
```

to aspx

```
Next >
<%= the_raw_value %> 
>>
```